# Python List Comp with replace - ' a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, replace

I am trying to split up a tab delimited byte object in to lines and fields.  In my input data when a field is supposed to be empty the data has -- . I want to replace -- with something that will act as a empty when I use it to build a mysql insert ''.  I am new to list comprehension but I found a few examples that seemed similar.

```
for line in line_split[1:]:
    field_split=line.split(b'\t')
    field_split = [x.replace('--', '') for x in field_split]
    print("f-", field_split)
    report_list.append(field_split)
```

If I comment out the replace line that errors so it can print, I get back the following line. If you scroll right the field value i want to replace shows b'--'.  This seems like it should be a simple fix but I have messing around for way longer then I care to admit

```
f- [b'1020569383', b'X012312', b'42132LVPG0U', b'Glow', b'Sports', b'Glow', b'Amazon', b'18.85', b'18.85', b'11.61', b'10.67', b'1.54', b'36.02', b'inches', b'0.52', b'pounds', b'Lg-Std-Non-Media', b'USD', b'6.02', b'2.83', b'0.00', b'--', b'--', b'--', b'3.19']
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove `--`?

Comment: `field_split = [x.replace(b'--', b'') for x in field_split]` is probably what you need. Looks like you're dealing with bytes, not strings.

Comment: Abdou - why dont you submit that as the answer so I can give you credit,  It is correct.  I tried [x.replace(b'--', '') for x in field_split] earlier but for some reason forgot the b on the replacement string

Comment: @Abdou I'm sorry but this is simple list comprehension, why do you think I incorporated your solution? And why do you think only you could come up with a solution as your comment? I'm just curious is all

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two options. First is to remove it from the dict-

```
x = [b'1020569383', b'X012312', b'42132LVPG0U', b'Glow', b'Sports', b'Glow', b'Amazon', b'18.85', b'18.85', b'11.61', b'10.67', b'1.54', b'36.02', b'inches', b'0.52', b'pounds', b'Lg-Std-Non-Media', b'USD', b'6.02', b'2.83', b'0.00', b'--', b'--', b'--', b'3.19']
final_list = [i for i in x if i != b"--"]
```

Or replace it with `''` -

```
final_list = [i.replace(b"--", b"") for i in x]
```

What's that `b` in front of these texts? If you do `type(x[0])` you get `<class 'bytes'>`. So you need to perform your operations in `byte` string also, hence the `b""`